# Git: How to remove submodule reference without removing the submodule repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree

As the title says I want to remove just a reference to other repository from my main repository without removing the files from that repository. As I can see all commands from git removes the repository files and I do not want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with:

```sh
git submodule deinit {{SUBMODULE_PATH}}
rm -rf .git/modules/{{SUBMODULE_PATH}}
```

Comment: Doesn't rm -rf remove all files from the repository?

Comment: No, it removes the submodules reference stored into the git control files.

Comment: Deinitializing the submodule removes its working tree, but the OP seems to want to keep it... so I’m not sure why this answer is accepted...